# ¿Como usar correctamente los JOINs para este caso?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy diseñando una BBDD para guardar el horario de una tienda, voy por el primer paso que es saber que días trabaja la tienda y tengo las siguientes tablas

[image]

**`dias`:** contiene los dias de la semana con su respectivo `ID`.

**`tiendas`:** solo contiene el nombre de la tienda su respectivo `ID`.

Y bueno al momento de hacer una consulta, me gustaria saber que dia o dias trabaja una tienda, pero al momento de ejecutar

```
SELECT * FROM tiendas_dias 
WHERE tiendas_id = 1;
```

tengo el siguiente resultado

[image]

Y quiero que donde dice **`dias_id`** en vez de aparecer el `id` del dia me salga el nombre del dia que tiene asociado ese `id`.

Comment: Quité las etiquetas irrelevantes pues Laravel aquí no tiene nada que ver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aplica un `inner join` con tu tabla **dias** y para agregar el nombre solo anexa `dias.nombre_dia` a tu `select`.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT tiendas_dias.id,tiendas_dias.tiendas_id,dias.nombre_dia FROM tiendas_dias 
INNER JOIN dias ON dias.id=tiendas_dias.dias_id 
WHERE tiendas_dias.tiendas_id = 1;
```

y si requieres agregar las tiendas

```
INNER JOIN tiendas ON tiendas.id=tiendas_dias.tiendas_id
```

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias! esto es exactamente lo que queria hacer, gracias a tu codigo y unos repasos que le he hecho a los joins ya tengo una mejor idea de como funcionan.

Answer (score 1):

Haz uso de `INNER JOIN` para vincular ambas tablas.

Razones:

- Tienes una tabla con una llave primaria `id`
- Tienes una tabla con una llave foránea `dias_id`

Las 2 columnas antes mencionadas están vinculando a las 2 tablas, por lo que vamos a trabajarlas en la sentencia `ON` para: recuperar las filas de la tabla de la izquierda `dias` con la tabla de la derecha `tiendas_dias`. La acción anterior solo obtendrá las filas que en ambas tablas estén vinculadas, descartando todas las demás.

```
SELECT dias.nombre_dia, tiendas_dias.dias_id
FROM dias
INNER JOIN tiendas_dias ON dias.id = tiendas_dias.dias_id
WHERE tiendas_dias.tiendas_id;
```

**Referencias**

- [Inner Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la edición @LuisCazares